# Removing WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW or WS_EX_APPWINDOW does not work

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I run a exe from my application.

I dont want that exe's taskbar icon to be shown on taskbar.

So I first took a HWND of that exe using `FindWindow` and then I used `SetWindowLong` function

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW)
```

but this is not removing the icon of that exe from Taskbar. I also used `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` instead of `WS_EX_APPWINDOW.`

Comment: Toolwindow style should be added, not removed. See  also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262726/determining-if-a-window-has-a-taskbar-button

Comment: This means i should use this function  SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) this way.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`? Do you know what `~` means? Do you understand bitwise operations yet? And did you read the dupe Q and A?