# how to hide taskbar entries in Windows via API programming

Tags: windows, taskbar

I have got an internal helper app without user interface which is started from another program which interacts with the user. I do not want a taskbar entry for the helper app. But anyway, a Window exists. I need an API call which removes the taskbar entry of the window. I know the Window Handle and the Process ID of the helper app. I have seen that there are calls in specific libraries, but I need the base API calls.

Comment: I have got some additional hints, but not the solution. You can browse through the windows by `GetWindow (hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)` and if you have got a process ID, you can query the window handle by GetWindowThreadProcessID. Perhaps we can set a window property. In the very similar OS/2 API, there is a "switch list" with several API calls, but Windows does not know this direct access. In OS/2, you can also set Session properties via Session ID (not window handle) for hiding all windows of the session in the tasklist. But I did not find any Windows API calls for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reverse answer (how to query if a window has got a taskbar entry) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262726/determining-if-a-window-has-a-taskbar-button).

To get or not to get a taskbar entry, you have to use SetWindowLong instead of GetWindowLong and you have to select a suitable combination of Window Styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the factors that affect whether a window has a corresponding task bar entry:

- Whether it has a parent.  A window with a parent is a child window (and thus should also have `WS_CHILD`).  A window without a parent is a "top-level" window.  Top-level windows generally do get a task bar entry.
- Whether it has an owner.  The documentation can sometimes be ambiguous by often blurring the distinction between an owner and a parent.  But it's possible for a non-child window to have an owner.  Dialog boxes and tool panels are typical examples of top-level windows that are owned.  Owned windows generally do not have a task bar entry.
- Whether is has any of these extended window styles:

  - `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` forces a task bar entry even if the window is owned.
  - `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` prevents the window from having a task bar entry, but has other effects as well.  It's for a specific, unusual type of application window and should not be used just to prevent a task bar entry.
  - `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` prevents a top-level window from having a task bar entry.  Note that it also affects the style of the non-client area.

When you don't want the other side effects form `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` or `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`, the best way to prevent the window from being listed in the task bar is to have it owned by another top-level window.

If you have a window that should be listed in the task bar but isn't (e.g., because it has an owner), then apply `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`.

You set extended window styles when you create a window.  You can update the styles for an already-existing window by using SetWindowLongPtr with `GWL_EXSTYLE`.  You might need to use SetWindowPos (possibly with `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`) after changing styles for the window to update to reflect the new style.